# Node, Webpack HTML page with full URL about the linked resources

Tags: html, node.js, webpack, webview

I created a simple HTML page and uploaded it to the remote service. In order to use Webpack and some other JavaScript libraries, I configured Node (v. 17.4) also.

This webpage will be integrated into a mobile application using a web view. Due to certain limitations, I cannot directly define the remote URL within the web view. Instead, I need to download the entire HTML, perform some manipulations, and then load the modified HTML into the web view. For example, in the iOS application, I'm using the loadFromString method of the web view.

However, using this approach, the web view does not have the ability to download external resources such as images and CSS, as it doesn't know the base URL. For various reasons, we would like to avoid specifying in the mobile application the baseURL into the `loadHTMLString` method:

```
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString as String, baseURL: baseUrl)
```

So, here's the question: Is there any way to obtain the full URLs of the linked resources when building the page? For example, can we define these full URL paths during the npm run build command?

Ultimately, the desired outcome would be to have something like this:

```
<script defer="defer" src="https://mydomain/mobile/mypage/bundle.js"></script>
```

Instead of this:

```
<script defer="defer" src="bundle.js"></script>
```